# CSS animation to split button into 2 options on click

Tags: javascript, css

In an HTML form, I have a simple button - very similar to the ones showcased here https://codepen.io/sebj54/pen/oxluI

```
.btn {
  position: relative;

  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0;

  overflow: hidden;

  border-width: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);

  background-color: #2ecc71;
  color: #ecf0f1;

  transition: background-color .3s;
}
```

I want to use a CSS (or Javascript) based animation that, when the button is clicked, generates 2 other buttons in the same div that display the 2 options that offer logical follow-up to this one. How can I accomplish this? Any suggestions for fancy transitions to the same would also help.

Comment: This is really a "can you code this for me" request. Look into javascript innerHTML to change the contents of your DIV, and try writing the code yourself without asking for a full solution. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 1):

Add an eventListener on click. After that, you can just create two new buttons and place them instead of the original button. A very simple example:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('clickBtn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(el) {
  var btn1 = document.createElement("button");
  var btn2 = document.createElement("button");
  var span1 = document.createElement("span");
  var span2 = document.createElement("span");
  span1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("btn1"));
  span2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("btn2"));
  btn1.appendChild(span1);
  btn2.appendChild(span2);
  btn1.className = "btn green";
  btn2.className = "btn orange";
  btn1.type = "button";
  btn2.type = "button";
  btn.parentNode.appendChild(btn1);
  btn.parentNode.appendChild(btn2);
  btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
}, false)
```

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;

  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0;

  overflow: hidden;

  border-width: 0;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.btn:hover, .btn:focus {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}

.btn > * {
  position: relative;
}

.btn span {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
}

.btn:before {
  content: "";
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
    
  border-radius: 100%;
  
  background-color: rgba(236, 240, 241, .3);
  
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.btn:active:before {
  width: 120%;
  padding-top: 120%;
  
  transition: width .2s ease-out, padding-top .2s ease-out;
}

/* Styles, not important */
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
  color: #34495e;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.btn.orange {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.btn.orange:hover, .btn.orange:focus {
  background-color: #d35400;
}

.btn.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.btn.red:hover, .btn.red:focus {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="btn red" type="button" id="clickBtn"><span>Extra-long button to let you appreciate the effect.</span></button>
</div>
```